# ModelView data not passed from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

My problem is that strongly typed data passed from my Controller to my view comes out empty (all it's properties are null).

I would also like to bind selected value in radiobuttons (marked as QUESTION2) to model property "GivenAnwser" but it doesn't seem to work either.

Type passed around is a ViewModel

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {  
            QuestionViewModel question = Manager.GetQuestion();
            return View(question);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(QuestionViewModel question,Anwser givenAnwser)
        {      
            //QuestionViewModel  is returned but all it's properties are null.           
            return View(question);
        }
    }
```

VIEW

```
@model Quiz.ViewModels.QuestionViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Html.Label("Question:")

@if (Model.CorrectAnwser != null)
{
    //some code
}

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question.Text)

//I have tried with Hidden fields and without them
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Question)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Anwsers)
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{         
    foreach (var anwser in Model.Anwsers)
    {
        //QUESTION 2
        <input type="radio" name="givenAnwser" value="@anwser" />
        <label>@anwser.Text</label>
        <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Check!" />
}
```

QuestionViewModel

```
public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public QuestionViewModel()
        {
            this.Anwsers = new List<Anwser>();
        }

        public Question Question { get; set; }

        public List<Anwser> Anwsers { get; set; }

        public Anwser GivenAnwser { get; set; }

        public bool CorrectAnwser { get; set; }

    }
```

EDIT:
ModelState contains an error:
     "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Quiz.Models.Anwser' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

Comment: Should work with the hidden fields.  Does QuestionViewModel have a parameterless public constructor, and are the properties (Pytanie,Odpowiedzi) also read/write?  Is it posting the correct values to the hidden fields?

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes it does. I have added the code for ViewModel to the post. It does post correct values to hidden fields. Edit: ModelState comes as Invalid.

Comment: The hidden fields must be inside the form...which is what will be posted to the server...

Comment: I have moved hidden fields under the foreachloop however there is no change.

Comment: That was just a hint...lets think together, you have an array, how it could be possible to bind that to a hidden field? Another hint, Question is a complex type, the hidden value is just a string...do you see?

Comment: ..I would make an elaborated answer but I am not in my dev machine...so please take a look: http://blog.codeinside.eu/2012/09/17/modelbinding-with-complex-objects-in-asp-net-mvc/ . You are making a couple of mistakes in the view definition.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I have updated my post with ModelState error. I did not know that HiddenFor could only store strings but when you think about it then how could it store an complex object. I think that I know what to do now: Pass ie QuestionID and then handle it in Post Controller.

Comment: Yes, you can change this behaviour, but by default you can just serialize primitive types to the standard input fields (except the FileUpload). And remember, if you post something to your controller, everything must be inside the form that has the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="radio" name="givenAnwser" value="@anwser" />
```

this line is setting a complex type "@answer" as the value of the radio button.
this might just do a ToString() of the type during rendering.

When you post it back, MVC might be trying to convert this string value back to

```
Quiz.Models.Anwser
```

and failing.

you should probably render

```
<input type="radio" name="givenAnwser" value="@anwser.SomeBooleanValue" />
```

p.s. also, why not use the Html Extension to render the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind a complex type (Question) to a Hidden field.  You would need to bind to the separate child properties.

Also, for the answers, don't use a foreach, use a for loop.  Like:

```
@for(var i=0;i<Answers.Count;i++)
{
    <input type="radio" name="@Html.NameFor(a=>a.Answers[i].answer.Value)" value="@Model.Answers[i].anwser.Value" />
}
```

or

```
@for(var i=0;i<Answers.Count;i++)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.Answers[i].answer,Model.Answers[i].answer.Value)
}
```

Although, that may not be correct either because Answers is a collection of a complex type as well, and you didn't share it's definition.

All in all, I don't think you really need (or want) to post back the entire Model back anyhow.  Why not just post back the question ID, and the selected Answer?